# Young diagrams for the block matrices

Tags: rt.representation-theory, permutations

Let S_n be the group of permutations of n elements. Consider map S_n -> S_mn of block permutations, and an irreducible representation of S_mn (over complex numbers), corresponding to Young diagram Y. Naturally, it decomposes into direct sum of irreducible representations for S_n. Is it possible to give a formula for the decomposition?

Block permutations: Consider S_n as matrices in GL(n), embed GL(n) into GL(mn) as block matrices with scalar blocks of size m * m, then you got the embedding S_n -> S_mn

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is "plethysm." See, e.g., Chapter 7 Appendix 2 of Stanley's "Enumerative Combinatorics, Vol. 2." But, for most plethysms, we do not have any kind of nice formula. So likely the answer is "it is not (at the moment) possible to give a formula for the decomposition."

Comment: Thank you, Sam, checking it out

Comment: It is not what I am looking for. The symmetric group changes as well

Comment: Dear Sam, may be you can figure it out better than I will. The "block permutations" are actually permutations of the tensor product of n-dimensional by m-dimensional vector spaces, and it is easy to decompose the respective tensor powers as S_n representation. My doubts are related to the "rest" of the Young diagram for S_mn. Is it "negligible" in any reasonable way?

Comment: Thank you, @SamHopkins for your thoughts!

Comment: It seems I do know the answer. Consider S_n x S_m and two irreducible representations \lambda and \mu. Induce a representation of S_mn from the subgroup. It is irreducible. Young diagram Y for the induced representation may be computed from the diagrams for \lambda and \mu. Multiplicity for \lambda equals dimention of \mu.

Comment: I don't follow your last comment: $S_n \times S_m$ is naturally a subgroup of $S_{n+m}$, not $S_{nm}$. It's true that induction from $S_n \times S_m$ to $S_{n+m}$ corresponds to the usual (not plethystic) product of Schur functions. But I don't think that's what your asking about. I still think that your "block embedding" of $S_n$ into $S_{nm}$ should correspond to some kind of plethysm.

Comment: No, no @SamHopkins. Let S_n act on V_n, S_m on V_m. Then S_n x S_m act on V_n \otimes V_m, which has dimension n*m. I am not talking about the usual product of Schur functions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142327/discussion-between-andrey-radul-and-sam-hopkins).